# Asp.Net MVC Routing in page load

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

On my RouteConfig, I have Controller and Action name placed on the Default Route.

```
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Controller", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }               
                );
```

While in page load, now the path is just 'http://geomig.com/'.

Is it possible to display full path, means 'http://geomig.com/Controller/Index' on page load.

Please help me.

Comment: You need to have some kind of URL rewrite. Or have another action as a default and then redirect to the actual action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need rewrite the path using **RewritePath()** method.

Use the following link to know how **RewritePath()** works:

[RewritePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wkk6d.aspx)

Example:

```
string originalPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToLower();
if (originalPath == "/")
    Context.RewritePath("/Home/Index");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the controller and action defaults. Simply have

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }                                    
            );
```

Comment: In this no controller name and action specified. then mvc knows to go to a page ? .I tried this, it gives me error page

Comment: Hi @SlightlyMoist , if you remove the default controller and action name then you have type complete url . What if I what to call action just by typing the domain like 'http://geomig.com/' in this case 
?

Comment: @Raju , If you remove the default controller name and action name you have type complete url i.e 'http://geomig.com/Controller/Index'. For your problem you need an other action which redirects to current default action as "Nilesh" said.

Comment: Yes, I really thanks you guys for helping me. I just used another action and then did the redirection. It worked for me. Thanks.